# Брать по несколько элементов в списке в цикле Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список изображений

```
['IMG_0023_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0023_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_715_10.tif', 
'IMG_0023_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_475_30.tif', 
'IMG_0024_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0024_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0024_840_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_715_10.tif', 
'IMG_0025_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0026_475_30.tif', 
'IMG_0026_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0026_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0026_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0026_840_20.tif']
```

Мне нужно в цикле брать по 5 элементов в списке, делать с ними некие операции и брать следующие.
Тоесть я беру первые 5 изображений, что-то с ними делаю. Потом беру следующие 5 и т.д.

Как брать по 5 элементов в списке?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

используйте [срезы](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html)

```
arr = ['IMG_0023_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0023_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_715_10.tif', 
'IMG_0023_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_475_30.tif', 
'IMG_0024_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0024_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0024_840_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_550_20.tif', 
'IMG_0025_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_715_10.tif', 
'IMG_0025_840_20.tif', 'IMG_0026_475_30.tif', 
'IMG_0026_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0026_670_30.tif', 
'IMG_0026_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0026_840_20.tif']

for i in range(0, len(arr), 5):
    print(arr[i:i + 5])
```

вывод:

```
['IMG_0023_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0023_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0023_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0023_840_20.tif']

['IMG_0024_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0024_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0024_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0024_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0024_840_20.tif']

['IMG_0025_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0025_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0025_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0025_840_20.tif']

['IMG_0026_475_30.tif', 'IMG_0026_550_20.tif', 'IMG_0026_670_30.tif', 'IMG_0026_715_10.tif', 'IMG_0026_840_20.tif']
```

Comment: Отлично! благодарю